# pyspark s3 path with special characters cannot be read

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, path, special-characters

I tried searching for an answer for this but was unsuccessful.  I have an s3 path that looks like this `kafka_logging_test/topics/something/partition=1/something+1+0000000004.json` and when I try to read it in pyspark like

```
testdf = spark_session.read.json("s3a://kafka_logging_test/topics/something/partition=1/something+1+0000000004.json")
```

I get the error

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o563.json.
: java.lang.NullPointerException: null uri host. This can be caused by unencoded / in the password string
```

However when I read a different path without special characters like '+' and '=' the read is successful which leads me to believe they are the reason for the failure.  Can someone tell me how to deal with these special characters such that the read is successfull for the original s3 path?

Comment: what is the outcome when you run ```import glob glob.glob("s3a://kafka_logging_test/topics/something/partition=1/*.json")```?

Comment: @LuizViola it looks like its an empty list

Comment: try to replace the ```=``` by ```%```

Comment: @LuizViola same error unfortunately

Comment: can you try ```testdf = librarian.spark_session.read.json("s3a%3A%2F%2Fkafka_logging_test%2Ftopics%2Fsomething%2Fpartition%3D1%2Fsomething%2B1%2B0000000004.json")```?

Comment: @LuizViola sorry, just did a test and it seems like even an object w/o the special characters is causing the same problem so it must be an issue with the bucket itself.  I think I'll delete this question.

Comment: @LuizViola it looks like buckets are not allowed to have underscores in them, I create an invalid bucket name.